# Use a variable name to name a dynamically created array(or scalar)

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I want to use $i value in @array_mem_depth_$i  so that my dynamically created arrays look like @array_mem_depth_1024,@array_mem_depth_512.

How to achieve this?

```
while(<FH>) {
$line = $_;
chomp($line);
foreach my $i (@depth_uarr) { if ( $line =~ /$i/) {push (@array_mem_depth_${i}, $line);} }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) explains why this is a bad idea. You should use nested structures as GMB used.

Answer (score 5):

I would not actually recommend having variables with dynamic names. While this might be technically feasible, this would make your code far more complex, for no obvious benefit.

Instead, why not have a hash of array references. Based on your partial code, this would look like:

```
my %h;
while(my $line = <FH>) {
    chomp($line);
    foreach my $i (@depth_uarr) { 
        if ( $line =~ /$i/ ) {
            push @{ $h{$i} }, $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. My FH is pointing to file having few lines like rf_1024,sr_512, sr_4096, rf_512, rf_435, sr_435, rf_123, sr_321 etc. And my depth_uarr is ("rf", "sr"). Now, I am reading in the file. Matching each line againt content of array and then binning it againt the value of arrays. For example, I am reading file and trying to read 2 array bins  arr_rf and arr_sr. For example, arr_rf would have all the $lines having matching rf and similarly for sr. Hash prints out an Array address. How to read it?

Comment: @RamneekSinghKakkar: you need to iterate over the hash keys, and print arrays one by one. Or better yet, use a module like [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to stringify the whole structure.